# How to fetch the nested record of another nested list of a document?

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

I am facing difficulty in retrieving the nested document object of another nested list. Please help me to resolve the same. My mongoDB document is as follows:

```
{ 
"_id" : "PT5", 
"departmentId" : "DEPT5", 
"subDepartmentList" : [
    {
        "subDepartmentId" : "SUBDEPT19", 
        "subDepartmentName" : "X-Ray",  
        "labServiceList" : [
            {
                "_id" : "123abc", 
                "subDepartmentId" : "SUBDEPT19", 
                "labServiceName" : "serviceOne"
            }, 
            { 
                "_id" : "123def", 
                "subDepartmentId" : "SUBDEPT19", 
                "labServiceName" : "hello", 
                }
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "subDepartmentId" : "SUBDEPT21", 
        "subDepartmentName" : "Haemotology",
        "labServiceList" : [
            {
                "_id" : "456abc", 
                "subDepartmentId" : "SUBDEPT21", 
                "labServiceName" : "abcd", 
                }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

From the above document I want to retrieve only one object of labServiceList by using its _id value(Ex: "_id" : "123abc" in this document). And I don't want to get any other fields apart from the matching nested document. I have tried with the below query:

```
db.labServiceMasters.aggregate([
{"$project": {
    "subDepartmentList": {"$filter": {
        "input": '$subDepartmentList.labServiceList',
        "as": 'labServiceList',
        "cond": {"$eq": ['$$labServiceList._id', '123abc']}
    }},
    "_id": 0
}}
```

])

Also I have tried using $map operator, but nothing goes in my way. Please help me to resolve this problem. And also please help me to write the query for the same using mongoTemplate in Java. Any suggestions would be appreciable. Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually need to nest a `$map` inside the `$filter` and another `$filter` inside the `$map`. And use `$arrayElemAt` to get the single entries:

```
db.labServiceMasters.aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "subDepartmentList": {
      "$arrayElemAt": [
        { "$filter": {
          "input": {
            "$map": {
              "input": "$subDepartmentList",
              "as": "sd",
              "in": {
                "$arrayElemAt": [
                  { "$filter": {
                    "input": "$$sd.labServiceList",
                    "as": "ls",
                    "cond": { "$eq": [ "$$ls._id", "123abc" ] }
                  }},
                  0
                ]  
              }
            }
          },
          "as": "sd",
          "cond": { "$ne": [ "$$sd", null ] }
        }},
        0
      ]
    }  
  }}
])
```

Returns:

```
{
    "_id" : "PT5",
    "subDepartmentList" : {
        "_id" : "123abc",
        "subDepartmentId" : "SUBDEPT19",
        "labServiceName" : "serviceOne"
    }
}
```

Which for spring-mongodb is:

```
    Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(
      project("subDepartmentList").and(new AggregationExpression() {
          @Override
          public DBObject toDbObject(AggregationOperationContext context) {
              return new BasicDBObject(
                "$arrayElemAt", Arrays.asList(
                  new BasicDBObject("$filter",
                    new BasicDBObject("input",
                      new BasicDBObject("$map",
                        new BasicDBObject("input","$subDepartmentList")
                          .append("as","sd")
                          .append("in",new BasicDBObject(
                            "$arrayElemAt", Arrays.asList(
                              new BasicDBObject("$filter",
                                new BasicDBObject("input","$$sd.labServiceList")
                                  .append("as","ls")
                                  .append("cond", new BasicDBObject("$eq", Arrays.asList("$$ls._id","123abc")))
                              ),
                              0
                            )
                          ))
                      )
                    )
                    .append("as","sd")
                    .append("$ne", Arrays.asList("$$sd", null))
                  ),
                  0
                )
              );
          }
      }).as("subDepartmentList")
    );
```

And serializes the same:

```
{
  "aggregate": "labServiceMasters",
  "pipeline": [
    {
      "$project": {
        "subDepartmentList": {
          "$arrayElemAt": [
            {
              "$filter": {
                "input": {
                  "$map": {
                    "input": "$subDepartmentList",
                    "as": "sd",
                    "in": {
                      "$arrayElemAt": [
                        {
                          "$filter": {
                            "input": "$$sd.labServiceList",
                            "as": "ls",
                            "cond": {
                              "$eq": [
                                "$$ls._id",
                                "123abc"
                              ]
                            }
                          }
                        },
                        0.0
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                },
                "as": "sd",
                "$ne": [
                  "$$sd",
                  null
                ]
              }
            },
            0.0
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: wowww:-) Thanks a lot Neil :-) You saved my day... This is what I wanted and struggled my whole day to achieve. In your answer, I have tried with shell's query and is perfectly fine. I could not try for the java query and I will try to execute the same little later and I am sure even that also works :-) Thanks a bunch once again :-)

Comment: Neil I tried to work with the Java query but I am failed to achieve as it is giving some compilation error, I have tried all my ways but nothing works. Please help me if you can trace the error. As I am using Spring if the Java query is by using mongoTemplate then it would be more helpful for me. Thanks :-)

Comment: @user3418760 This is cut and paste code right out of my IDE, so it certainly works. If you have problems it is because you are typing it out yourself. I suggest you similarly "copy" the code right from here simply use it until you understand how to write the pipeline yourself. Also check you have updated sping-mongodb to the latest version in your project.